# Issue running Flask App: create_app app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name]) KeyError: None

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I downloaded a Flask project from GitHub. I'm trying to run the Flask project in a virtualenv, but when I run the project in virtualenv it's throwing the following error:

> none
>   \app__init__.py", line 10, in create_app
>       app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
>   KeyError: None

**__init__.py:**

```python
from flask import Flask
from config import app_config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    from app import models 
    from app.home import home as home_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)
    return app
```

**config.py:**

```
   class Config(object):
   class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
   DEBUG = True
   SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
   class ProductionConfig(Config):
   DEBUG = False

   app_config = {
        'development': DevelopmentConfig,
        'production': ProductionConfig
   }
```

**run.py:**

```
    import os
    from app import create_app
    config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
    app = create_app(config_name)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Comment: Is `config_name` None?

Comment: Your question is missing a word at the end of the first sentence. Is the missing word  "virtualenv"?

Comment: @karel  Yes, Thank you.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I'll update my config.py code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to set your `FLASK_CONFIG` environment variable before trying to run your Flask app. This will **cause your environment configuration lookup to fail** i.e. `app_config[config_name]` will be `None` since `config_name` isn't instantiated. Can you try setting up your environment variables before running? For example, open up your terminal and set your `FLASK_CONFIG` environment variable to ***development*** then try rerunning your application, something along the lines of:

```
 # Macintosh Users
 export FLASK_CONFIG=development
 export FLASK_APP=<start_file> # <start_file> is probably run.py for the template
 flask run

 # Window Users
 set FLASK_CONFIG=development
 set FLASK_APP=run.py
 flask run
```

Hopefully that helps, if this doesn't solve your issue can you please paste your file which starts your application? This file is probably `run.py`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm trying to setting the environment variable. I'll add the main file which is starting app.

Comment: Ok so my explanation is the reason why, this line within run.py: config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') is looking for the environment variable FLASK_CONFIG so it can choose the appropriate configuration. Are you on a Macintosh?

Comment: No I'm using windows 10

Comment: Ok can you try: set FLASK_CONFIG=development then: set FLASK_APP=run.py then: flask run For reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/ and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I'll try now asap. Thank you for providing the reference.

Comment: I've set the FLASK_CONFIG AND APP inside my project folder. Once I run the project it's throwing the below error

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Unable to load configuration file (No such file or directory): 'C:\\Users\\pkumarar\\NhtTracker\\venv\\Fimple-master\\instance\\config.py'

Comment: The path is off, where are you trying to run from it needs to be correct?     app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True) is looking for a relative location for the config. I would double check the env variables you set. Alternativley, you can move into the folder holding run.py and do a python run.py and see if that works if so your FLASK_APP env variable is off

Comment: My project folder location is under Users\pkumarar\NhtTracker I've installed virutal environment inside the folder NhtTracker inside that NhtTracker folder I've my project folder "Fimple-master"

Comment: It sounds like your set up is off with virtualenv, but can you try moving to the directory holding your run.py file (on your terminal) then running your project with a: python run.py this should work regardless. the issue is with where you are trying to run it from and relative paths

Comment: Np glad you got it working, I would look into virtualenvwrapper it's a nice wrapper around virtualenv